# Create Network chart with filter in python

Tags: python, pandas, networking, plot, charts

Hi I have a table with the following structure :

| serial_num | FAMILY_ID | ID2 | ID1 | RELATIONSHIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A11 | x1,x2,x3,X4 | x1 | x2 | CHILD |
| A11 | x1,x2,x3,X4 | x1 | x3 | SPOUSE |
| A11 | x1,x2,x3,X4 | x1 | x4 | CHILD |
| A12 | x5,x6,x7,X8 | x5 | x6 | CHILD |
| A12 | x5,x6,x7,X8 | x5 | x7 | CHILD |
| A12 | x5,x6,x7,X8 | x5 | x8 | SPOUSE |
| A11 | x1,x2,x3,X4 | x1 | x1 | MOVIL |
| A12 | x5,x6,x7,X8 | x5 | x5 | MOVIL |

with 1,000,000 rows

and I want to make a network chart with a filter (show only the relations where the user input is in the family_id)

so basically my question is divide to 2
first and most important : how I create network chart (with the type of relation on the connecting line )
second: how to I apply a filter so before I create the table it will slice to only the relevant family_id base on ID that the user insert

[desired output for the example without the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrE0s.png)

[desired output for the example with filter of x3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72jBl.png)

Comment: please provide enough rows to have a meaningful example (maybe 5-10), and a schematic of the matching expected chart

Comment: @mozway edited  (the charts are in the links)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) with [`graphviz`](https://graphviz.org/):

```
import networkx as nx

# building graph from pandas
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.rename(columns={'RELATIONSHIP': 'label'})
                              .query('ID1 != ID2'), # remove self-edges
                            source='ID2', target='ID1',
                            edge_attr='label') # defining edge label

# plotting
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph
A = to_agraph(G)
A.layout('dot')
A.draw('output.png')
```

output:

[image: complete graph]

Filtering the subgraph containing `x3`:

```
H = G.subgraph(next(x for x in nx.connected_components(G) if 'x3' in x))

A = to_agraph(H)
A.layout('dot')
A.draw('output2.png')
```

[image: filtered graph]